# How to compute the VaR(a) of the following cdf

Tags: quantiles, cumulative-distribution-function

I have to compute the mean value, the variance, the VaR and ES of the CDF

F(x)= 1- (3/2x)^(-3) if x>= 3
F(x)=0 if x< 3

The mean and variance I have computed, but what about computing the value at risk and expected shortfall if I am not given a alpha level??

Comment: Welcome to CV. This question is best answered based on the BIS III recommendations. That said, why not simply assume one of the standard levels for alpha as discussed in the BIS literature?

Comment: yes but anyway I have no clue how to proceed. Is not the quantile function the inverse of cumulative distribution function? So just inverse the function and that it?

Comment: You are right about the quantile and cdf functions.